# Is the random data at the end of my decrypted message supposed to be there?

Tags: aes, padding, ecb, pkcs11

This is my PKCS#5 & AES/ECB Python 3.3 code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def encrypt_snap(media):
    key = bytes('M02cnQ51Ji97vwT4', 'utf8')
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
    padded = media + ((16 - len(media) % 16) * chr(16 - len(media) % 16))
    encrypted = cipher.encrypt(padded)
    return encrypted

def decrypt_snap(media):
    key = bytes('M02cnQ51Ji97vwT4', 'utf8')
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
    padded = media + ((16 - len(media) % 16) * chr(16 - len(media) % 16)).encode('utf8')
    decrypted = cipher.decrypt(padded)
    return decrypted

msg = 'hello world! :)'
print(msg)
encrypted = encrypt_snap(msg)
print(encrypted)
decrypted = decrypt_snap(encrypted)
print(decrypted)
```

This is what it returns:

```
hello world! :)
b'M\xd0g\xca\xa2x\x91\xf5\xa5\x9ao\x1d\x8ev^@'
b'hello world! :)\x01\x02\xf9K\x95\x01\xb9\xdaG\x03D\x94\x88\x9bi)w'
```

Should that "random" (?) data be at the end of the decrypted message? Is that all part of the padding?

Please let me know if I've done anything wrong. Thanks! :)

Comment: I don't know Python but here's my two cents: Comment out the `padded=...` lines from your code. Does the issue persist? Plus I think the question is better suited for CodeReview.SE or SO. Cheers

Comment: Actually, it appears that, during the decryption process, you're adding padding and then decrypting the padded message.  Yes, that decrypted padding would look like gibberish...

Comment: Apart from the padding issue, this code is very wrong cryptographically. 1) It uses ECB mode, no integrity protection, no IV 2) It uses an UTF-8 encoded key. A key is supposed to be random binary data, not text.

Comment: Handling a key like that is all sorts of wrong. 1) Hard coded keys means they are no keys at all, for the purpose of cryptography. The attacker knows the program. If you just want that for test cases, then write that in a testing function. *Not* in the encrypt/decrypt functions 2) as CodesInChaos already pointed out, UTF-8 and then only using alphanumerical values means you are not using an actual key. If you want to use passphrases/passwords, you **need** a password-based key derivation function.

Answer (score 4):

As poncho said in his comment, you added padding before decryption as well, which is not correct. AES encryption and decryption are both permutations, so if you decrypt data with a key, it will "look" random (at least, if AES is secure).

Instead of adding padding, you need to remove the padding from the already decrypted text:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def encrypt_snap(media):
    key = bytes('M02cnQ51Ji97vwT4', 'utf8')
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
    padded = media + ((16 - len(media) % 16) * chr(16 - len(media) % 16))
    encrypted = cipher.encrypt(padded)
    return encrypted

def decrypt_snap(media):
    key = bytes('M02cnQ51Ji97vwT4', 'utf8')
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
    decrypted = cipher.decrypt(media)
    padding_bytes = decrypted[-1]
    return decrypted[:-padding_bytes]

msg = 'hello world! :) how are you?'
print(msg)
encrypted = encrypt_snap(msg)
print(encrypted)
decrypted = decrypt_snap(encrypted)
print(decrypted)
```

Most notable are the lines:

```
padding_bytes = decrypted[-1]
return decrypted[:-padding_bytes]
```

In your padding scheme, the last byte of the message represents how many bytes of padding there are in total. So, we strip off that number of characters from the byte array. I also changed the message to be a little longer to make sure it worked correctly.

The above is still not perfect, however: it does not check to see if the padding itself is valid. For example, you might desire to iterate over the stripped bytes and make sure they are monotonically increasing starting from 1.

As a final warning, hopefully the above code is for learning purposes only. If you're actually trying to write secure code, you need to invest in a different mode of operation (e.g. CBC instead of ECB) as well as some authentication (e.g. HMAC). If it is for learning purposes, my apologies; I felt compelled to include this notice just in case.

Comment: Notice that at least in languages without built-in exception mechanism on index out of range (and arguably all languages), the value of `padding_bytes` should be checked to be in range [1..16] before use as `decrypted[:-padding_bytes]`. Same before peeking in `decrypted` to get `padding_bytes` as `decrypted[-1]` (also, both of these different syntaxes are alien to me, even if I get the intend from context).

Comment: @fgrieu It's especially "funny" if you'd regard the byte value as signed, you could be addressing bytes before or *after* the ciphertext. Not good, two-way buffer overrun, although usually limited.